# Way to extract several substrings from a string?

Tags: python, regex

I have a variable say `q`

```
q="today(Thursday)^05^*07*[2012]"
```

Is there a way to extract `Thursday` , `05` , `07` , `2012` separately  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
q = "today(Thursday)^05^*07*[2012]"
import re
print re.findall(r'\w+', q) # ['today', 'Thursday', '05', '07', '2012']
```

Comment: @burning_LEGION: it is easier to discard it afterwards than clutter up the regex to make it not match in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative (though I prefer [@thg435 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11344285/463065)):

```
r=re.split('[\^*()[\]]', q) #['today', 'Thursday', '', '05', '', '07', '', '2012', '']
```

then

```
r[1::2]
```

yields

```
['Thursday', '05', '07', '2012']
```

*Aside*: Does anyone know why I am getting the interleaved empty strings? Easy to work around, but it would be better to not have them in the first place.

Comment: To avoid empty strings, add `+` to the character class, otherwise it matches an empty string between two consequent delimiters.

Comment: @thg435 Thanks for the suggestion .. I've been looking for a reason for these empty strings .. adding `+`  to `'[+\^*()[\]]'` is still not working for me :-/ -- what am I missing? I think it must be something obvious.

Comment: Sorry, I meant add it after the class, `[\^*()[\]]+`

Comment: @thg435 Great, thanks .. that works much better! (still get a trailing empty string at the end .. regex can be tricky. If you have an idea why I still get that trailing `''` please let me know, otherwise, don't worry about it and thanks for the help. More reason to prefer your solution, less complex, and works better.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex:

```
(?<=\()(.+)(?=\))|(?<=\^)(.+)(?=\^)|(?<=\*)(.+)(?=\*)|(?<=\[)(.+)(?=\])
```

Comment: `q = "today(Thursday)^05^*07*[2012]"
import re
print re.findall(r'(?<=\()(.+)(?=\))|(?<=\^)(.+)(?=\^)|(?<=\*)(.+)(?=\*)|(?<=\[)(.+)(?=\])`
', q)

Comment: Error : Unsupported characters in input

Comment: Yes i have aligned it . And regex is really cluttered .

Answer (score 0):

Use string seperators.

`string.split[^*]` etc.

Comment: Yes i did . Its tedious though . Have to apply for all the special characters .

Comment: The first answer was pretty good . So went with that . thanks anyway :)